# append to a field of array with eloquent

Tags: laravel, mongodb, eloquent

I have an application with laravel and mongodb. With elequent iam trying to append a new value to an array stored in a field.

So this is an example of a document. Iam trying to append a new value to the projects field.

```
 {
"_id":{
  "$oid":"5f80513714450000a6007c90"
},
"organization_id":"5f80304214450000a6007c81",
"user_id":"5f80513714450000a6007c8f",
"status":true,
"role_id":"5c148783fe412ba8333074ec",
"company_id":"5f80511f14450000a6007c8e",
"updated_at":{
   "$date":"2020-11-09T18:42:03.000Z"
},
"created_at":{
  "$date":"2020-10-09T12:01:59.000Z"
},
"projects":[
  "5fa33513416100008d0070ba",
  "5f80429814450000a6007c85",
  "5f80436714450000a6007c86"
]
}
```

in my model i have created this method

```
public function push_user_projects($data, $where_data) {
    return UserAccountsModel::where($where_data)->put($data);
}
```

The where_data works good. The method finds the correct documents to update.
But what doesent work is the pushing part. The following is what i put into data parameter

```
                $data = array(
                'projects' => array(
                    $projectData["_id"]
                )                 
            );
```

And when i se the result a complete new array has updated the projects field with the new value. But i want to append the value to the existing array. Can someopne help me?

Answer (score 0):

To push another element into your data variable under 'projects'

```
$data['projects'][] = $projectData["_id"];
```

Comment: The data variable is already good. Iam trying to push the value in data variable inside my mongodb document field with my eloquent model